# Reloading Unity Scene doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using this code to fade in a CanvasGroup at the beginning of my scene loading, and then if the player loses I want to fade out the scene and reload it from the beginning.

```
void Update () {
    if (Time.time < 1 && fade.alpha >= 0)
        fade.alpha = .99f - Time.time;
    if (fadeOut)
        fade.alpha += .02f;
    if (fade.alpha >= 1)
    {
        Debug.Log("Change scene");
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when it hits this it shows the gamescene twice in the hierarchy, and neither one on the screen. I'll upload a picture below.  When it does this is also hits the Debug.Log repeatedly. [image] 
 Does this not work if it's the only scene in the project? Only thing I can think of.

I've updated the method to include a boolean to ensure it SHOULD only run one time.  Somehow it is still running countless times until I end the unity editor.  The new update method is this :

```
void Update () {
    if (Time.time < 1 && fade.alpha >= 0)
        fade.alpha = .99f - Time.time;
    if (fadeOut)
        fade.alpha += .02f;
    if (fade.alpha >= 1 && !reloadStarted)
    {
        Debug.Log("Change scene");
        reloadStarted = true;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess `Update` is executed more rapidly than the scene is reloaded. So it starts to reload on every update. Introduce a bool property to indicate, that reload is already started.

```
if (fade.alpha >= 1 && !isReloadStarted)
{
    Debug.Log("Change scene");
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    isReloadStarted = true;
}
```

Furthermore according to your description, you might want to reload when `fade.alpha` is **less or equal to 0**.

```
fade.alpha <= 0
```

Comment: Very strange, even with the bool in place it still runs the Debug.Log multiple times. I'm not sure how this is even possible.  The if most definitely checks for the alpha AND the false boolean, yet even when I tell it to print the boolean value it will print true as it runs multiple times.

Comment: Try making IsReloadStarted a static boolean. It might be that every new instance of your script is also executing the code. 
A static boolean should prevent that.

Comment: This seemed to fix one problem and add another somehow.  Now fade.alpha += 0.2f is only run once for some reason, even though the Update function continues to be called, and fadeOut continues to be true.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up refactoring the code and implementing this in a completely different way.  I still don't know why it was acting so weird.